# What are some good Web Tools to help me format my code for blogs?

Tags: blog, formatting

**What are some good Web Tools to help me format my code for blogs?**

I'd like to be able to copy & paste my code into textbox/textarea and have the web tool format it nicely for various popular blogging sites.

Features: Color, indentation, line numbers, etc.

Languages: C/C++/C#, VB.net, XML/HTML/Xaml, Ruby, etc.

Bloging sites: [Blogger](http://blogger.com), [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com), etc

Comment: Is this for your own blog, or for responding to other people's blogs?

Comment: My own blog, blogger/wordpress.  No intention of showing code as a comment on someone else's blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub's [gist](http://gist.github.com) service has a rather neat embedding tool and recognises loads of different languages. I've use this to embed code snippet occasionally.

Also anything based around [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) works great, I've had good experiences with the [CodeColorer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codecolorer/) plugin for wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

There is a guide on how you can do this here: http://codeblog.kello.se/2009/01/07/getting-code-formatting-with-syntax-highlighting-to-work-on-blogger/

It's based on syntaxhighlighter which you can read more on here http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

Comment: I like http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat as it's web-based.  I'd rather not download & install anything as I blog from various computers (PCs, Macbooks, Linux boxes, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I like John Skeet's Code Formatter on his [C# in Depth blog](http://csharpindepth.com/CodeFormatterTool.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best tool I've used for the purpose is [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). How it works and samples you can find [here](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html).

Answer (score 0):

I like [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) and it's now incorporated into many blog sites including [WordPress](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/) by default.